# PyQt5 attach data to QComboBox item

Tags: pyqt5, qcombobox

Is it possible to attach generic data to each `QComboBox` item so that I can retrieve it based on current selection?

I know I could build a `dict` with combo items as keys, but that is rather fragile as it will break on any item edit.

I seem to remember there's a way to attach custom data to almost anything in Qt, but I'm unable to find info (and I might be confusing with other frameworks; it's years I don't touch Qt).

I seem to understand I could dynamically add items using `addItem(text, userData)`; can I do the same statically in Qt Designer?

Optimum would be to be able to attach data directly in Qt Designer and be able to retrieve it in `currentIndexChanged` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't set data "statically" in Designer, at least with the standard QComboBox control.

This is because the `itemData()` of an item can be *any* kind of data, and Qt natively supports a "limited" range of data types as [QVariants](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html), and while on PyQt it seems that any arbitrary type of data can be added the truth is that internally PyQt tries to convert recognized types to its own, and fall backs to a private PyQtObject to encapsule other things (python `object` subclasses).

There are some possibilities using promoted widgets or custom Designer plugins, but implementing a similar approach in the correct way is usually not worth it.

The basic rule is that on Qt you can only set widget *properties* (Qt properties, those listed in the "Properties" section of the documentation of each class), and for widgets that have internal models (like QComboBox or higher level views such as QListWidget) only the basic data roles are available: basically, the text and the icon, plus font/alignment, foreground/background, tooltip/whatsthis and flags/checkstate for item views.

Any other "property" (which are not *actual* properties) such as item data for custom roles can only be set programmatically.

If you want to have a more consistent access to item data in a QComboBox you can just use the dict to initialize it, and then access its [`model()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#model) (which by default is a [QStandardItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html)), or, eventually, create a model on your own using the dict and use [`setModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#setModel).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there some way to attach data to a generic QWidget (without subclassing)? Specific (current) case is to attach some data to pages in a QTabWidget, but question is more general, of course. TiA

Comment: @ZioByte Yes, you can use [`setProperty(name, value)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty) on any class that inherits from QObject (which also means all QWidget subclasses, obviously). You can use dynamic properties in Designer too, so you can set a property for every widget added to a QTabWidget. Just select the widget in the object inspector of Designer, and click the "+" button in the property editor to add a property. As explained before, only basic [QVariant] types can be used.